# Ipad cannot play audio and video at the same time on my web app

Tags: ipad, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am trying to play HTML5 Audio and Video at the same time on my web app but it seems to stop the other when one is played. For example if I play audio video will stop or if video is played audio will stop.

Comment: Did you try the app on a PC to see if you have the same problem there?

Answer (score 1):

It will work on PC, but not on iPad. iPad loads or plays only one tag (audio/video) at once. In a series of .play() commands, the last .play(); command will work...

For to make it work you will need multiple interaction from the user.

Comment: So there is no practical way of playing an audio and video file at the same time in mobile safari?  Could you do so in an app wrapper with a modified safari?